# Questition about SQL - INSERT with DISTINCT and JOIN

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm trying to merge two tables (table1, table2) and insert the new table (table3) in my database. The point is, I need to use the "DISTINCT"-Statement because the number in table1 is not unique.

Here is my Code-Example:

```
MySQLCommand command = new MySQLCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table3(number, value, account, date) " + 
"SELECT DISTINCT(table1.Number), table1.value, table1.account, table2.date FROM table1 " +
"INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.number = table2.number"
```

I get the Error "The reading from the stream has failed".

Even, when I trying just

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(table1.Number) FROM table1 " +
"INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.number = table2.number"
```

or different JOIN-Statements, e.g.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(table1.Number) FROM table1 " +
"LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.number = table2.number"
```

Thank you for some hints!

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function**. It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT table1.Number, table1.value ...` to make things clearer.

Comment: To add to jarlh's comment, the result from `select distinct col1, col2 from tbl` can also be done with a GROUP BY:  `select col1, col2 from tbl group by col1, col2`. Except that with a GROUP BY you can also add aggregation functions like SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, COUNT, ...

Comment: I might be tempted to use insert..on duplicate key

Comment: @P.Salmon If table3 is new, then it's empty.  So if you insert distinct values there's no dups to update.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answers! I figured out, when I'm using DISTINCT and GROUP BY without the JOIN-Statement it works fine. But what's wrong with my JOIN-Statement?

Comment: If you want the number's that are in both tables, then you need an INNER JOIN. A LEFT JOIN returns all from the left side of the join, so it would be useless here because it would get all table1.number by default.

Comment: @LukStorms - I should have qualified my comment by saying  forget the DISTINCT clause in the select if an insert on duplicate key is appropriate. And it may be, there is a date going to table3 which may mean the last date entry from table 1 may be of more interest than a random one.

Comment: @P.Salmon Ah ok. Well, then he could just group by and use a `MIN(table2.date)` or `MAX(table2.date)`. Then it won't be random.

Comment: I checked my Syntax more then twice and used your ideas, but unfortunately I get always an error. I assume there's something wrong in my tables. I try now to remove duplicates from table2 and create a new table. Hopefully, my JOIN-Statement will work… Thank you guys!